# Planes and other artifacts In Tango Point Cloud

Tags: google-project-tango

In my app I update `mPointCloudmanager` at every `onXyzIjAvailable`. I save `TangoXyzIjData` and relative `TangoMatrixTransformData` when a button is pressed.
Here's the code:

    TangoXyzIjData xyzIjData = mPointCloudManager.getLatestXyzIj();

```
TangoSupport.TangoMatrixTransformData matrix =
    TangoSupport.getMatrixTransformAtTime(
        xyzIjData.timestamp,
        TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
        TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH,
        TangoSupport.TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_OPENGL,
        TangoSupport.TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_TANGO);
```

Then I apply matrix transformation to the points inside `TangoXyzIjData` and save them to a file.

This results in a reconstruction with a decent precision, but it comes also with some strange artifacts floating in the air.
Here's a screenshot of a pointcloud of the front of my bin. You can see that the bin is well formed, but has some planes that floats before him.
[Point cloud screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syixt.png)

Where does this artifacts come from?
May I be doing something wrong somewhere? Or it's just Tango Limitation?
Is there any technique to get rid of those planes?

Comment: I can see the the floating point cloud in the upper part of the image, but I couldn't understand the bottom image. But anyway, could it be just a reflective surface or light factor? IR based depth sensor always has problem with black, reflective surface or strong light source..

Comment: @JasonGuo: the image in the bottom is the same point cloud. Just rotated left to emphasize the artifacts I was talking about.  
As user interface using something really similar to [java_point_cloud_example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/java_point_cloud_example). And in the render provided from this example I cant see any plane, but in the reconstruction they are there.